# How to create an array of objects containing multiple key-value pairs in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am getting response from my server as an array of objects shown below:

```
[
    {_from: "A/1", _to: "A/2", status:"ok"},
    {_from: "A/2", _to: "A/3", status:"ok"},
    {_from: "A/1", _to: "A/3", status:"ok"}
]
```

I would like to convert this into an array as shown below in **Typescript**:

```
[
    {from: 1, to: 2},
    {from: 2, to: 3},
    {from: 1, to: 3}
]
```

I am a newbie in TypeScript and getting confused with the concept of the key-value pair. Any help with this is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is how you can do it, using JavaScript/TypeScript's [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). You can iterate through the array, and split the values, and return the required object.

```js
const a = [{_from: "A/1", _to: "A/2", status:"ok"},
{_from: "A/2", _to: "A/3", status:"ok"},
{_from: "A/1", _to: "A/3", status:"ok"}];

const res = a.map(({_from, _to}) => ({
  from: (_from.split('/'))[1],
  to: (_to.split('/'))[1],
}));

console.log(res);
```